# Adding a tooltip that will give percent of category for a specific duration

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

So I have loaded this table in PowerBI. As a tooltip on a 'Line and Clustered Column Chart', I want to show the percentage of people that belong to the 'Very High', 'Very Low', 'High' category, etc based on the segment column that you see in the image. I also want it to be restricted for a specific month so those percentage metrics should be just for May, June, etc individually. Any thoughts on how can I go about doing this?

This is a screenshot of my sample data:

[image]

Please note that I'm very new to PowerBI and this could be something very obvious but I still am not sure on how I can proceed on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this measure did the work

VH % = CALCULATE(SUM([PEOPLE_COUNT]),[SEGMENT]="Very High")/SUM([PEOPLE_COUNT])

And then inserting that measure inside the tooltip automatically gets the appropriate value across month.